# Groupby and drop NaN rows while preserving one in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a test dataset as follows:

```
   id city   name
0   1   bj    NaN
1   2   bj   jack
2   3   bj    NaN
3   4   bj    jim
4   5   sh    NaN
5   6   sh    NaN
6   7   sh  steve
7   8   sh  fiona
8   9   sh    NaN
```

How could I groupby `city` and drop `NaN` rows for `name` while preserving one only for each `group`? Many thanks.

The expected result will like this:

```
   id city   name
0   1   bj    NaN
1   2   bj   jack
2   4   bj    jim
3   5   sh    NaN
4   7   sh  steve
5   8   sh  fiona
```

New dataset read by `df = pd.read_clipboard(na_filter = False)` from excel file, please note `N/A` should not be considered as `NaN`:

```
      newcode build_name  floor  rent_id      rent_name
0  1210010403         C栋     25  1765228   （株）有延商店上海事务所
1  1210010403         C栋     25  1765229            N/A
2  1210010403         C栋     25  1765229            N/A
3  1210010403         C栋     25  1765229            N/A
4  1210010403         C栋     25  1765230  上海皇瑾文化传媒有限公司 
5  1210010403         C栋     25  1765229            N/A
6  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231     上海农邦实业有限公司
7  1210010403         C栋     25  1765232            N/A
8  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231   上海农NA邦实业有限公司
```

Code: `df[df['rent_name'].ne('N/A') | ~df.duplicated(subset=['newcode', 'build_name', 'floor'])]`, same result with `df[~(df['rent_name'].eq('N/A')  & df.duplicated(subset = ['newcode', 'build_name', 'floor'], keep = 'first'))]`

Out:

```
      newcode build_name  floor  rent_id      rent_name
0  1210010403         C栋     25  1765228   （株）有延商店上海事务所
4  1210010403         C栋     25  1765230  上海皇瑾文化传媒有限公司 
6  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231     上海农邦实业有限公司
8  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231   上海农NA邦实业有限公司
```

You can see one `N/A` row is missing in the result, I don't know why.

Desired output:

```
      newcode build_name  floor  rent_id      rent_name
0  1210010403         C栋     25  1765228   （株）有延商店上海事务所
1  1210010403         C栋     25  1765229            N/A
4  1210010403         C栋     25  1765230  上海皇瑾文化传媒有限公司 
6  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231     上海农邦实业有限公司
8  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231   上海农NA邦实业有限公司
```

Comment: You are not dropping nans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain condition for test not missing values or first duplicated values per `city`, name:

```
df = df[df['name'].notna() | ~df.duplicated(subset=['city', 'name'])]
print(df)
   id city   name
0   1   bj    NaN
1   2   bj   jack
3   4   bj    jim
4   5   sh    NaN
6   7   sh  steve
7   8   sh  fiona
```

EDIT: For test strings `N/A` use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df = df[df['name'].ne('N/A') | ~df.duplicated(subset=['city', 'name'])]
print(df)
   id city   name
0   1   bj    N/A
1   2   bj   jack
3   4   bj    jim
4   5   sh    N/A
6   7   sh  steve
7   8   sh  fiona
```

If want test multiple values use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask:

```
df = df[~df['name'].isin(['N/N','N/A']) | ~df.duplicated(subset=['city', 'name'])]
print(df)

   id city   name
0   1   bj    N/A
1   2   bj   jack
3   4   bj    jim
4   5   sh    N/A
6   7   sh  steve
7   8   sh  fiona
```

EDIT:

```
df = df[df['name'].notna() | ~df.duplicated(subset=['city', 'name'])]
print(df)
   id city   name
0   1   bj    NaN
1   2   bj   jack
3   4   bj    jim
4   5   sh    NaN
6   7   sh  steve
7   8   sh  fiona
9  10   gz    NaN
```

EDIT1: For test duplicated is necessary add column with `NaN`, here `rent_name`:

```
df =  df[df['rent_name'].ne('N/A') | 
         ~df.duplicated(subset=['newcode', 'build_name', 'floor', 'rent_name'])]
print (df)
    
      newcode build_name  floor  rent_id     rent_name
0  1210010403         C栋     25  1765228  （株）有延商店上海事务所
1  1210010403         C栋     25  1765229           N/A
4  1210010403         C栋     25  1765230  上海皇瑾文化传媒有限公司
6  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231    上海农邦实业有限公司
8  1210010403         C栋     25  1765231  上海农NA邦实业有限公司
```

Answer (score 5):

Boolean select `NaNs`, drop the last duplicated in `name` and `city`

```
df[~(df.name.isna() & df.duplicated(subset = ['city', 'name'], keep = 'first'))]

    id city   name
0   1   bj    NaN
1   2   bj   jack
3   4   bj    jim
4   5   sh    NaN
6   7   sh  steve
7   8   sh  fiona
```